# Schedule tasks on windows 11: administrator has no permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-11, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

Trying to schedule a task, Enter user account information for running this task.
User account selection drop down:

```
 sa
 abc700ge5d28c9a2
 <myUserAccount>
```

Where do the first two user accounts come from? I did not create these accounts.
My account is administrator. Select my account and input password, error:

```
user unknown, incorrect password or no permissions
```

Tried many times, no luck.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you're just asking what some accounts on your computer are, don't add the rest of the info. If you're asking how to set up a task, you don't need multiple accounts to schedule a task, so you should probably do a bit more reading on that. Either way, use the EDIT button and focus and clarify your question. One question per post.

Comment: Resolving the permissions is more important.